# Problem with WordPress Elementor linked image and Round Corners Going Square Again

Tags: plugins

I am using WordPress 5.8.3 on 64 bit Windows 10 and 64 bit Firefox 96.0.1.

I have used Elementor to add a hyperlink to an image in one page, to lead to another page. The page is based on one of the defaulting themes, and is a consistent shade of lighter green.

I have inserted an image file, a .jpg with square corners. My image as been altered to display with rounded corners with a purple border with thickness of 2, and is placed within the first page, which is accomplished in the page, via the image, and Elementor settings.

When logging out of WordPress to test my progress without WordPress running, but just the default install webserver serving the page, I can click on my img href link. It does indeed work, and accurately leads on to the next desired, second, web page.

My problem is that after the hyperlink image has been clicked on, the visual result is that square corners are displayed again, coloured white, and not green, or “transparent”.

[image]

What can I do so that my hyperlink image maintains its rounded corners after clicking, and does not display what seems to be squared off white corners? Is there something simple I can do, still for free, such as add some additional .css at the bottom of Dashboard\Appearance\Customize ?

Comment: It sounds like the corners are CSS on the page it's displayed on, and when you click the link you're going to the original raw image. Is that right? What's the URL you see for the image? At that point WordPress isn't involved in showing the image, it's loaded directly from static files on your server by your browser. If you want that version to have the rounded corners you'll either have to change what happens when you click on the image or store the image on the server pre-rounded.

Comment: The Page with this hyperlink image is: http://127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/
The page that it links to is:  http://127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/main/.                                                                                                 What I can do is use a CSS plugin to insert extra css per Page.  I have 'Post/Page specific custom CSS' installed.  Is there anyone who can reply with css instructions I can insert in my Splash page to keep the corners rounded and green, even after a mouse click?  I am after a simple, generic solution!

Comment: I also think  that my square corners "injection" problem is to do with an oversight CSS, or the PHP. Now, I have a free plugin called, **Post/Page specific custom CSS**, but I do not have the means to purchase CodeKit. Is my problem something that is/will be fixed as the free version of Elementor does get updated? Can someone reply back here, with the steps I can systematically take to prevent my square corners problem? I don't have the ability to access the code being put into my Page by WordPress, to manually engineer a systematic solution. Can someone reply with a solution here, please?